# React JS - Modal only appearing once

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a Sign in modal using react which opens on a button click. The problem is that  only appears once.
Here's the code for the modal

```
import { Modal } from "components/Modal";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function SignInModal(props: any) {
  const { showSignInModal } = props;
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(showSignInModal);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(showSignInModal);
  }, [showSignInModal]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onDismiss={() => {
          setIsOpen(false);
        }}
        title=""
      >
        <div className="text-white">Hello World</div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the code for my index.js file

```
 const [showSignInModal, setShowSignInModal] = useState(false);

  function handleOpenConnect() {
    setShowSignInModal(true);
  }

return (
    <>
 <Button onClick={handleOpenConnect} >
  Sign In
 </Button>
<SignInModal showSignInModal={showSignInModal} />
</>
)
```

When I press the button again, it does not appear. I want it to appear each time the button is clicked.

Comment: What's the purpose of `isOpen` in the modal component? If you want the state to be handled from the parent component then **only** use that state. Dismissing the modal would update the state in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The modal component is creating its own local copy of state and updating that local copy.  So future updates to the *parent's* state don't change anything in that modal component.

Don't duplicate state.

If the modal should be controlled by the parent, it doesn't need its own internal state.  Let it rely on the value provided:

```
export default function SignInModal(props: any) {
  const { showSignInModal, setShowSignInModal } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        isOpen={showSignInModal}
        onDismiss={() => {
          setShowSignInModal(false);
        }}
        title=""
      >
        <div className="text-white">Hello World</div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And pass in both the state and the setter:

```
<SignInModal showSignInModal={showSignInModal} setShowSignInModal={setShowSignInModal} />
```